# What authentication process does twitter use for its web clients?

Tags: authentication, cookies, twitter, oauth

Does Twitter use cookie based authentication for its regular web client or does it use some form of OAuth or xAuth ?

Also, after I enter my user name and password into my twitter account from a web client, I don't see a HTTP post happening on the browser. It remains static and in a while my home page gets loaded. How does this kind of authentication happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter uses a version of OAuth as explained at: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq